# Displaying random sprite from Atlas Phaser

Tags: phaser-framework

I'm trying to add 1 out of the 5 images in atlas randomly, but they all show up one on top of the other, is there a way to fix this? Basically I want 1 of the sprites to display could be any of the 5 every time I run my level, but all I get is all 5 at the same time.

```js
///Declaration

 this.load.atlas('Monsters', 'images/monsters.png', 'images/monsters.json');


////Where I call sprite

 this.figuritaspega = this.game.add.sprite(0, 0, 'Monsters');
        this.figuritaspega.frame = this.rnd.integerInRange(0,4);
         this.figuritaspega = this.game.add.group;
        this.figuraarriba = this.add.sprite(1015, 140, this.figuritaspega);
        this.figuraarriba.scale.set(0.9 , 0.9 );

////.json below

{"frames": [

{
 "filename": "amarillo.png",
 "frame": {"x":0,"y":0,"w":188,"h":200},
 "rotated": false,
 "trimmed": false,
 "spriteSourceSize": {"x":0,"y":0,"w":188,"h":200},
 "sourceSize": {"w":188,"h":200}
},
{
 "filename": "azul.png",
 "frame": {"x":188,"y":0,"w":240,"h":200},
 "rotated": false,
 "trimmed": false,
 "spriteSourceSize": {"x":0,"y":0,"w":240,"h":200},
 "sourceSize": {"w":240,"h":200}
},
{
 "filename": "naranja.png",
 "frame": {"x":428,"y":0,"w":162,"h":200},
 "rotated": false,
 "trimmed": false,
 "spriteSourceSize": {"x":0,"y":0,"w":162,"h":200},
 "sourceSize": {"w":162,"h":200}
},
{
 "filename": "rojo.png",
 "frame": {"x":590,"y":0,"w":190,"h":200},
 "rotated": false,
 "trimmed": false,
 "spriteSourceSize": {"x":0,"y":0,"w":190,"h":200},
 "sourceSize": {"w":190,"h":200}
},
{
 "filename": "rosa.png",
 "frame": {"x":780,"y":0,"w":231,"h":200},
 "rotated": false,
 "trimmed": false,
 "spriteSourceSize": {"x":0,"y":0,"w":231,"h":200},
 "sourceSize": {"w":231,"h":200}
}],
"meta": {
 "app": "http://www.codeandweb.com/texturepacker",
 "version": "1.0",
 "image": "monsters.png",
 "format": "RGBA8888",
 "size": {"w":1011,"h":200},
 "scale": "1",
 "smartupdate": "$TexturePacker:SmartUpdate:41785e106df91b6daf42364753f15c41:5fca3c08999ac8d93eabfac98fafaf65:8fc4d3ec51ba7bc700054b5f64cf62b1$"
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't really know what you are trying to do here, but I do know there are a couple of programming mistakes.

First you add a `Phaser.Sprite` and assign it to var `figuritaspega` which is good, but then you create a `Phaser.Group` and assign that also to the same var `figuritaspega`? I think it's better to have a separate variable for the group.

Secondly, `add.group` is a function call so you should add `()` to indicatie it's a function call instead of assigning the function to the variable.

And finally, when you add a sprite to `figuraarriba` the parameters are 1015, 140, this.figuritaspega, but the expected parameters are `x,y,key,frame` ([see here](http://phaser.io/docs/2.6.1/Phaser.Sprite.html)), so basically you are passing the sprite/group `this.figuritaspega` as if it's a spritesheet? That won't work.

Like I said, I'm not entirely sure what you are trying to do here, or what is the reason of adding only one sprite to a group? But I guess maybe something like this will work:

```
// create a sprite, random frame 0..4
this.figuritaspega = this.game.add.sprite(0, 0, 'Monsters');
this.figuritaspega.frame = this.rnd.integerInRange(0,4);

// create a group
this.mysprites = this.game.add.group(); // <- function call
this.mysprites.add(this.figuritaspega);

// scale entire group and reposition group
this.mysprites.scale.set(0.9 , 0.9 );

// notice that the sprite position is relative to the group position
this.mysprites.x = 10;
this.mysprites.y = 20;
```

Comment: Thanks for the tips helped a lot :), this (this.rnd.integerInRange(0,4);
) and fixing my errors did the trick.